# Longest Arithmetic Progression

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Given a list of numbers **arr** (not sorted) , find the Longest Arithmetic Progression in it.

Arrays: Integer a

1 ≤ **arr.size()** ≤ 10^3. **and**
-10^9 ≤ **arr[i]** ≤ 10^9.

Examples:

**arr** = [7,6,1,9,7,9,5,6,1,1,4,0] -------------- **output** = [7,6,5,4]

**arr** = [4,4,6,7,8,13,45,67] -------------- **output** = [4,6,8]

```
from itertools import combinations
def arithmeticProgression2(a):
    n=len(a)
    diff = ((y-x, x) for x, y in combinations(a, 2))
    dic=[]
    for d, n in diff:
        k = []
        seq=a
        while n in seq:
           k.append(n)
           i=seq.index(n)
           seq=seq[i+1:]
           n += d
       dic.append(k)      
   maxx=max([len(k) for k in dic])
   for x in dic:
       if len(x)==maxx:
           return x
```

in case **arr.size()** is big enough. my code will be run more than 4000ms.

Example :

**arr** = [randint(-10**9,10**9) for i in range(10**3)]

**runtime** > 4000ms

***How to reduce the space complexity for the above solution?***

Comment: This is badly indented, please fix.

Comment: Have you read numerous articles concerning `the Longest Arithmetic Progression` ?

Comment: You say that the runtime is greater than 4 seconds, but then finally you ask to reduce ... the **space** complexity?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. sr this is my first post. I will try to get better.

Comment: @MBo yes, i  have. but most of them talk about sorted array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things that makes the code slow is that you build series from scratch for each pair, which is not necessary:

- you don't actually need to build *k* each time. If you just keep the step, the length and the start (or end) value of a progression, you know enough. Only build the progression explicitly for the final result
- by doing this for each pair, you also create series where the start point is in fact in the middle of a longer series (having the same step), and so you partly do double work, and work that is not useful, as in that case the progression that starts earlier will evidently be longer than the currently analysed one.
- It makes your code run in O(n³) time instead of the possible O(n²).

The following seems to return the result much faster in O(n²), using dynamic programming:

```
def longestprogression(data):
    if len(data) < 3:
        return data
    maxlen = 0 # length of longest progression so far
    endvalue = None # last value of longest progression
    beststep = None # step of longest progression

    # progressions ending in index i, keyed by their step size, 
    # with the progression length as value
    dp = [{} for _ in range(len(data))]

    # iterate all possible ending pairs of progressions
    for j in range(1, len(arr)):
        for i in range(j):
            step = arr[j] - arr[i]
            if step in dp[i]:
                curlen = dp[i][step] + 1
            else:
                curlen = 2
            dp[j][step] = curlen
            if curlen > maxlen:
                maxlen = curlen
                endvalue = arr[j]
                beststep = step

    # rebuild the longest progression from the values we maintained
    return list(reversed(range(endvalue, endvalue - maxlen * beststep, -beststep)))
```

Comment: What is the memory requirement for this technique? O(n^2)?

Comment: Indeed, space complexity is O(n²)

Comment: Using Greedy method O(n^2) you can reduce the memory to O(n).

Comment: Feel free to post an answer ;-)