# How can I find the longest sub-array that is an arithmetic progression?

Tags: python

If I have a list like this `[2, 33, 54, 3, 7, 11, 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]`

How can I find the longest arithmetic progression?

The output should be: `[15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5]`.

Here's my code but it does not work and of course there are a lot of bugs.

Can anyone help?

```
def find_arithmetic(lst):
    temp = 0
    cnt = 0
    max = 0

    for i in range(0,len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i+1] - lst[i] == lst[i+2] - lst[i+1]:
            temp = i
            cnt += 1
        if max < cnt:
            max = cnt
        return str(lst(i,max+1))

print(find_arithmetic([12, 33, 54, 3, 7, 11, 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]))
```

Comment: What is your definition of `arithmetic`? It seems like you mean [longest arithmetic subsequence](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-arithmetic-progression-dp-35/)?

Comment: What do you mean by longest arithmetic? Longest sequence of values that can be produced by a single mathematical operation (e.g. in this case by repeatedly subtracting 2, but maybe in some other case by repeatedly adding 5, or multiplying by 3, or something else)? Something more specific? We can't answer without a proper description of what you want (ideally with more than just one example to illustrate, since the one example given could obey multiple rules of varying degrees of specificity).

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp I think they mean arithmetic progression.

Comment: btw: don't use `max` as a variable name; there's no reason to return a str; rather than your comparison something like `max_val = max(max_val, cnt)` is probably clearer; if you start at 0 you don't need to tell `range()` (because of its overloaded forms).  these are all orthogonal to the problem, but worth mentioning

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Longest Arithmetic Progression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150179/longest-arithmetic-progression)

Comment: i gave an example because my english is not good .
and i am still a beginner

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp IMO that's not a good duplicate target because the asker wants an arithmetic progression that is not necessarily in consecutive elements of their list. e.g. they want `[7,6,5,4]` from `[7,6,1,9,7,9,5,6,1,1,4,0]`, and that introduces additional complexities that aren't seen here.

Comment: i am sorry but it does not  answer my question because that code is looking for index that have the same difference with another index and the index is not next to the previous index

Comment: @KellyBundy I was talking about the question Joshua linked as a duplicate. The asker there says: `arr = [7,6,1,9,7,9,5,6,1,1,4,0] -------------- output = [7,6,5,4]`. Sorry my comment wasn't clear _which_ asker :)

Comment: @KellyBundy You're right, I "misspoke" :) I edited the title to "sub-array". In the future, you should feel free to edit the title as you see fit, since you have edit privileges at 7k reputation.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I would've if I had been certain about what they want. But I was only certain you were disagreeing with yourself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The defining property of an arithmetic progression is that consecutive elements have the same difference between them. So to find the longest sub-sequence that fits an arithmetic progression, you need to keep track of the difference between consecutive elements, and check that it is the same as the difference between the previous pair.

When this condition is satisfied, you bump up the end-index. If not, you say the current and previous element are the start of a new progression. Finally, you iterate over all the sequences you found and return the longest one.

```
def find_arithmetic_prog(sequence):
    progression_limits = [] # Make a list to keep track of the start and end indices of all progressions you find
    start = 0 # Assume your progression starts at the first element
    end = 1   # Assume your progression ends at the second element
    delta = sequence[1] - sequence[0]
    for index in range(2, len(sequence)):
        new_delta = sequence[index] - sequence[index - 1]
        if delta == new_delta: # The delta is the same as before
            end = index        # So extend the progression
        else:                  # The delta is different, so add the previous progression to our list and start a new one
            progression_limits.append((start, end))
            # A new progression from the previous index to the current one
            start = index - 1  
            end = index 
            delta = new_delta

    # Now that we've processed the entire list, we go through all the sequences we found
    # And return the longest one
    start, end = max(progression_limits, key=lambda item: item[1] - item[0])
    return sequence[start:end+1]
```

Running this with your input gives:

```
>>> find_arithmetic_prog([12, 33, 54, 3, 7, 11, 15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25
])
[15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5]
```

Comment: ohh thatnk you soo much, i needed an explaination and i got  
i really appreciate it

Comment: i am sorry that i am asking now but i was rying to write a code without lamda but i failed 
if you can help me...
thank you

Comment: Define a function that takes one argument `item` and returns `item[1] - item[0]`. Then do `key=that_function_name` instead of `key=lambda...` @Ramadan

Comment: it worked ,
thank you soo much ..